# Making website elements align to a (small) grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

So I have an idea for a site design where the background is a grid of small (say 10px) color-shifting squares.  Ideally, I'd like to have the elements on the page line up with this grid, however most of the guides for website grids revolve around the 960 grid system, which isn't small enough for my purposes.

Anyone have any suggestions for how to achieve this?  Also, if anyone has any ideas for how to do the color-shifting grid thing, I'd definitely appreciate that as well!

Comment: Please be a little more specific. What do you mean by colour-shifting? And what is it you want to achieve in the long run?

Comment: Do you mean you need squares as your background, which changes its' color frequently?

Comment: Yes, exactly what Surya said. Something like [this](http://www.cs.middlebury.edu/~dwhitehead/Photos/Color%20grid.jpeg), but all the colors are constantly shifting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how to create a constantly changing, multi-colored grid**

[image][image]

You can fill an 8x8 grid with rectangles (one at a time) like this:

```
    var n=parseInt(Math.random()*64);
    var r=parseInt(n/8);
    var c=n-r*8;
    ctx.fillStyle=randomColor();
    ctx.fillRect(c*20,r*20,20,20);
```

You can generate a random color like this:

```
    function randomColor(){
        return("#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
    }
```

Add an animation loop and you’re good to go!

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/n2ymp/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
          return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
          function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
        })();


        var fps = 30;
        function animate() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                requestAnimFrame(animate);

                // Drawing code goes here
                var n=parseInt(Math.random()*64);
                var r=parseInt(n/8);
                var c=n-r*8;
                ctx.fillStyle=randomColor();
                ctx.fillRect(c*20,r*20,20,20);


            }, 1000 / fps);
        }

    // create a random color object {red,green,blue}
    function randomColor(){
        return("#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
    }


    animate();        

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=400></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Holy cats that's awesome!  My original goal was to kind of have the colors gently shift and pulse, so I played around with yours a bit and ended up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/APuzT/).  I'm gonna mess around with it some more, but I'm actually starting to like yours better...

Comment: Ooh, [got it to work even better](http://jsfiddle.net/APuzT/2/).  Of course, I should've realized that averaging colors would lead to a lot of browns...